# Why is my Sieve so slow in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've looked at other Sieve implementations on Stackoverflow and other places and I don't see a massive difference in mine, yet theirs seems to work on a large scale. I know that mine works, but the problem comes when it gets to large number. once it hits those, it crashed the webpage.

```
/* My sieve of eratosthenes*/
function sieve(lim){
    var squareLimit=Math.sqrt(lim);
    var sArr=[];
    for(i=2;i<lim;i++)
        sArr[i]=true;

    for(var i=2;i<squareLimit;i++){

        if(sArr[i]){
            for (var j=i;j<lim;j++){
                sArr[i*j]=false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, I made the changes mentioned except for the adding part, I don't quite get that.

After fixing it, I got the speed where it needed to be and then I solved problem 7 in project euler. Yay :)

Comment: Variables "squareLimit", "i", and "j" should all be declared with `var`.  You don't need to multiply in the inner loop - you can just repeatedly add the value of "i". Addition is cheaper than multiplication.

Comment: Adding? I want to say I actually saw something about that and I think I got it to work but it still crashed the wegpage.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crashed the web page"?  Was there an error? If so, exactly what was it?

Comment: No error it just stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I see the problem:

```
        for (var j=i;j<lim;j++){
            sArr[i*j]=false;
        }
```

That should be:

```
        for (var j = i + i; j < lim; j += i) {
            sArr[j] = false;
        }
```

You only need to iterate in the inner loop up to the limit. Your code was just checking "j", not "j * i". Note that I also eliminated the multiplication too; that should save some time.

Comment: BAM, That worked. Thanks for a nice response. I really appreciate those who help out. I was getting really frustrated, but I see it now..... ok :)

Comment: Wait. shouldn't that be for(var j = i+i;j<lim;j +=i)

Comment: @ChrisJones oh yes probably. I'll edit the answer. *edit* yes, right, because you want to leave the primes `true`.

Comment: Hahaha, I am kind of glad you  made that mistake because it let me test myself a little bit, which is great :) but again, thank a ton.